# Resolvent estimate of hyperbolic Laplacian

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, micro-local-analysis

Consider the Laplacian $-\Delta$ on the hyperbolic space $\mathbb{H}^n$. For $\lambda \in \mathbb{C} \setminus [0, \infty)$, do we have resolvent estimates of the form
 $$\Vert (-\Delta - \lambda I)^{-1}\Vert \leq \frac{C}{|\text{Im}(\lambda)|}$$
which parallel the corresponding estimates from the Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$? A reference would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The proof is analogous to the Euclidian case.

Comment: Doesn't such an estimate hold for any non-positive self-adjoint operator, without using the specifics?

Comment: As pointed out by Paul, you trivially have such an estimate, with $C=1$, for any self-adjoint operator.